# Java avoid using too many if statement or too many validator classes

Tags: java

I am using lot of if statements to check.Like:

```
if(statement 1){ 
   block 1;
}
if(statement 2){
   block 2;
}
...//about at least 20 if
if(statement n){
   block n;
}
```

To avoid using too many if-statement, I have tried to use strategy pattern which would create validator class for each if-statement.Like:

```
public interface Validator<SomeObejct>{
    public Result validate(SomeObject o);
 } 

public class SomeValidator implements Validator<SomeObject> {
   @Override
    public boolean validate(SomeObject o) throw Exception{
        if(statement 1){ 
            block 1;
         }  
}
```

Because I may have at least 20 if-statement, it may need at least 20 validator classes. So if there is any better solution for that? Or how can I manage these 20 validotor classes?

Edit:

To be more specific, I am writing some code for checking the problem on my schedule. For example:

```
 if(currentDate > mustFinishDate){
     warning();
 }
 if(NotScheduleADateForThisTask){
    warning();
 }
 if(DateFormatNotCorrect){
    error();
 }
```

Above the date check may also be the if-statement block.

Comment: Are you using the if statements to test for only one variable or multiple variables, post an example of what you verify with the if statements.

Comment: Tell us more about your exact task. 20 `if` statements in a row sounds like a poor overall design.

Comment: Do you want to use your validators dynamically, or these are just 20 static 'if's?

Comment: If you have 20 completely distinct conditions, you will have 20 if statements, 20 classes, or 20 *somethings*. You can't just turn 20 conceptually different things into fewer than there actually are.

Comment: @Michael Thanks for your answer. In that case, I may need to think how to manage these 20 classes or 20 if statements in better way.

Comment: @KunLiu give us some context, it's hard to tell how to refactor `statement 1`, `statement 2` and `block 1;`, `block 2;`

Comment: What do you mean by "Or how can I manage these 20 validotor classes?"

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use the Composite pattern to maintain a list of all validators:

```
class ValidatorComposite<T> implements Validator<T> {
    List<Validator<T>> validators = new ArrayList<>();
    public void addValidator(Validator<T> add) { validators.add(add)); }

    public Result validate(T toValidate) {
        Result result = Result.OK;
        for (Validator<T> v : validators) {
            result = v.validate(toValidate);
            if (result != Result.OK) break;
        }
        return result;
    }
}
```

and since `Validator` only has one method, for Java 8 it's a functional interface, so you don't really need "20 classes" but can create a list on the fly using lambdas.

```
ValidatorComposite<SomeObject> val = new ValidatorComposite<>();
val.addValidator(so -> condition1 ? block1(so) : Result.OK);
val.addValidator(so -> condition2 ? block2(so) : Result.OK);
```

and so on.

Your code sample isn't really consistent because first you declare `Validator` to return `Result` and later let the implementation return `boolean` (and even throws an `Exception`), so I kind of intergrated both by ignoring the exception and using a `Result.OK` value.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. It inspire me a lot. I think this is a good way to manage my Validators.

Comment: @daniu Is it mandatory that the variables values have already been initialized ?

Answer (score 1):

these days what you should not probably care about is performance because of power of computers. now most programmers try to write readable and clean codes.

so i believe if writing 20 `ifs` makes your code easier to understand and more flexible its not bad to implement that.

BTW you can use `switch case` too.

```
switch (variable){
     case 1:{
     //block 1
      }
      case 2:{
      //block2
      }
      ...
}
```

if your cases are not similar and have different aspects using that `Validator` pattern will lead to inflexibility(It may lead to this point, it depends on situation).

Comment: I agree with your first two points, but the switch case is not the same as OP's example. If you put in the breaks in each case, it behaves like a sequence of if-else-if's, not as a sequence of if's.

Comment: In many cases, particularly if the value of `variable` is set by code that you maintain, much more readable, concise, and maintainable code is achieved by replacing switch-case blocks by an enum with a constant specific method or stored lambda.