# Java - Using Validators to implement variable numbers of "if" statements

Tags: java, validation, if-statement

According to the solution presented [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54008564/java-avoid-using-too-many-if-statement-or-too-many-validator-classes) by daniu, the Composite pattern can be used to maintain a list of Validators to test all the needed conditional tests. But I didn't understand how to use it. Below are my conditional tests and the provided code that he made available.

**My conditional tests:**

```
boolean namesPatientEqualAndMotherSimilar = (lvNamePatient == 0 && lvNameMother <= 10);
boolean namesPatientAndMotherSimilar = (lvNamePatient <= 10 && lvNameMother <= 10);
boolean equalOrSimilarBirthDate = (lvPatientBirth < 2);
boolean twin = patientTwin.equals("yes") && patient.getTwin().equals("yes");

if (namesPatientEqualAndMotherSimilar && equalOrSimilarBirthDate && twin) {
    return true;
} else if (namesPatientAndMotherSimilar && equalOrSimilarBirthDate && twin) {
    return false;
} else if (namesPatientAndMotherSimilar && equalOrSimilarBirthDate && !twin) {
    return true;
} else if (namesPatientAndMotherSimilar && !equalOrSimilarBirthDate) {
    return false;
}
```

**Validator interface:**

```
public interface Validator<SomeObejct>{
    public Result validate(SomeObject o);
}
```

**Interface implementation:**

```
class ValidatorComposite<T> implements Validator<T> {
    
    List<Validator<T>> validators = new ArrayList<>();

    public void addValidator(Validator<T> add) {
        validators.add(add)); }

    public Result validate(T toValidate) {
        Result result = Result.OK;
        for (Validator<T> v : validators) {
            result = v.validate(toValidate);
            if (result != Result.OK) break;
        }
        return result;
    }
}
```

**Use of implementation:**

```
ValidatorComposite<SomeObject> val = new ValidatorComposite<>();
val.addValidator(so -> condition1 ? block1(so) : Result.OK);
val.addValidator(so -> condition2 ? block2(so) : Result.OK);
```

Thank you in advance.

Comment: How did you get this variables lvNamePatient, lvNameMother ?

Comment: @Deepak Patankar Hi ! Through Levenshtein's distance algorithm.

Comment: I am trying to write it using validators. But it is becoming messy. Are you doing this for practicing composite validator or do you have a code and you want to improve it using desing patterns ?

Comment: @Deepak Patankar I want the code generic. If I need include some others conditional tests it's only add the new ones and it's done.

Comment: If you are doing it to improve the current code, I would say that it might be an overkill

Comment: Okay, I will add what I have got and we can see if it looks good

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For simplicity, lets assume that we have an `InfoObject` object with the fields.

```
public class InfoObject{
   boolean namesPatientEqualAndMotherSimilar;
   boolean namesPatientAndMotherSimilar;
   boolean equalOrSimilarBirthDate;
   boolean twin;
}
```

And our task is to validate that this InfoObject input is correct. One approach was to use the if-else condition, but if the number of validations required increases then the if-else code might become messy.

Next, we can directly use the `ValidatorComposite` class and define our custom validators.

```
ValidatorComposite<InfoObject> completeValidator = new ValidatorComposite<>();
val.addValidator(infoObject -> firstCheck(infoObject) ? Result.OK : Result.NOT_OK);
val.addValidator(infoObject -> secondCheck(infoObject) ? Result.NOT_OK : Result.OK);
val.addValidator(infoObject -> thirdCheck(infoObject) ? Result.OK : Result.NOT_OK);
val.addValidator(infoObject -> fourthCheck(infoObject) ? Result.NOT_OK : Result.OK);

Result result = completeValidator.validate(infoObject);
if(result == Result.OK){
  return true;
}
return false;
```

And we can define the following functions. Sorry for the functions name, I didn't know the actual use case, so used some dummy names:

```
public boolean firstCheck(InfoObject infoObject){
  return infoObject.getNamesPatientEqualAndMotherSimilar() && infoObject.getEqualOrSimilarBirthDate() && infoObject.getTwin();
}

public boolean secondCheck(InfoObject infoObject){
  return infoObject.getNamesPatientAndMotherSimilar() && infoObject.getEqualOrSimilarBirthDate() && infoObject.getTwin();
}

public boolean thirdCheck(InfoObject infoObject){
  return infoObject.getNamesPatientAndMotherSimilar() && infoObject.getEqualOrSimilarBirthDate() && !infoObject.getTwin();
}

public boolean fourthCheck(InfoObject infoObject){
  return infoObject.getNamesPatientAndMotherSimilar() && !infoObject.getEqualOrSimilarBirthDate();
}
```

**How does this code work?**

We defined a list of validators. The `validate()` function will call all the validators one by one, and it will stop when one of the validators returns the NOT_OK result.

In addValidator function, we have a lambda function `infoObject -> fourthCheck(infoObject) ? Result.NOT_OK : Result.OK`, which returns a functional interface.

There are a lot of concepts involved in this example, to learn about more concepts please refer to:

1. [Composite pattern](https://www.baeldung.com/java-composite-pattern)
2. [Lambda Expressions](https://www.baeldung.com/java-8-lambda-expressions-tips)

Answer (score 0):

If you replace -

`SomeObject` - Your class to be validated

`Result` - could be boolean in your case

Then the validator might look like -

```
ValidatorComposite<SomeObject> val = new ValidatorComposite<>();
val.addValidator(so -> namesPatientEqualAndMotherSimilar && equalOrSimilarBirthDate && twin);
val.addValidator(so -> !(namesPatientAndMotherSimilar && equalOrSimilarBirthDate && twin));
val.addValidator(so -> namesPatientAndMotherSimilar && equalOrSimilarBirthDate && !twin);
val.addValidator(so -> !(namesPatientAndMotherSimilar && !equalOrSimilarBirthDate));
```

Next you may run validations using the val object -

```
val.validate(yourObject)
```